# How to calculate data in multi partitions respectively?

Tags: sql, hive

For instance, there is a table tablea which comprises 3 partitions: day1, day2, day3.

Is it possible to calculate:

```
select count(distinct uid) as c1 from tablea where day = day1;
select count(distinct uid) as c2 from tablea where day = day2;
select count(distinct uid) as c3 from tablea where day = day3;
```

in one HQL without `'union'` then return `c1+c2+c3`?

`select .. from tablea where day between .. and ..` is incorrect.

---

#### Solved

This can be done by:

```
select sum(uid) 
from (
    select 
        count(distinct uid) as uid
    from tablea 
    where day between 'day1' and 'day3'
    group by day) a;
```

Comment: You do understand that this absolutely meaningfulness, business wise

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total of `day1 + day2 + day3`. Then I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = day1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = day2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = day3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM
    tablea
```

**Update**

I think you can also do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN day <= day1 AND day>=day3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
    tablea
```

Comment: I need to deal with over 50 partitions (assume day1 to 
 day50)..Is there any better solution? Like a `loop` in java?